# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a VAR(p) Process

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

In Lütkepohl's New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis Chapter 3, we try to estimate the model parameters via Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

We assume that $u=(u_1',\dots,u_T')'\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_T \otimes \Sigma_u)$, where the $u_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_u)$ are the error terms in
$$(y_t-\mu)=A_1 (y_{t-1}-\mu)+\cdots+A_p (y_{t-p}-\mu) + u_t.$$

We define $\mu^*:=(\mu',\dots,\mu')'$ ($T$ stacked $\mu$ vectors), $A:=(A_1,\dots,A_p)$ and $\alpha=vec(A)$.

Via maximum likelihood estimation we get the following estimators:
$$\tilde{\mu}=\frac{1}{T}\bigg(I_K - \sum_i \tilde{A}_i\bigg)^{-1}\bigg(\sum_t[y_t-\sum_i \tilde{A}_i y_{t-i}]\bigg),$$
$$\tilde{\alpha}=\big((\tilde{X}\tilde{X}')^{-1}\tilde{X}\otimes I_K\big)\big(y-\tilde{\mu}^*\big),$$
$$\tilde{\Sigma}_u=\frac{1}{T}\big(\tilde{Y}^0 - \tilde{A}\tilde{X}\big)\big(\tilde{Y}^0-\tilde{A}\tilde{X}\big)',$$
where and $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}^0$ are estimators of $Y^0:=(y_1-\mu,\dots,y_T-\mu)$ (with $Y^0_t:=(y_1'-\mu',\dots,y_{t-p+1}'-\mu')'$) and $X:=(Y_0^0,\dots,Y^0_{T-1})$, which are obtained by replacing $\mu$ with $\tilde{\mu}$ in $X$ and $Y^0$.

**My question: How are $\tilde{A}$ and/or $\tilde{\mu}^*$ estimated?**

Comment: It's been a long time since I read Lutkepohl but did you mean $\tilde \alpha$ or $\tilde A$. Also, what is $\tilde \mu^{*}$.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I do mean $\tilde{A}$ because the $\tilde{A}_i$ occur in the first estimation. I suppose if we calculate $\tilde{\alpha}$ first we get $\tilde{A}$ by $\tilde{\alpha}$'s definition. But your right we need $\tilde{\mu}^*$ for that and he doesn't tell us how to estimate that either if I'm not mistaken!

Comment: if the starred version of $\mu$ is nothing but the stacked $\mu$, the starred and tilded version of $\mu$ will be the stacked version of the tilded $\mu$, I would say.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I think you're right. However, wouldn't that mean that there is no way of consecutively explicitly computing these non-linear equations in their present form? I was assuming that should be possible. But it seems to me one would need to solve the system first.

Comment: I must not be following because I don't see an  $\alpha$ in the original model yet you're writing an expression for the estimate of it when you write $\tilde {\alpha} $.

Comment: @mlofton The $A_i$ occur in the model. $A:=(A_1,...,A_p)$ and $\alpha:=vec(A)$. So $\alpha=vec(A_1,...,A_p)$. These variables are defined by (3.3.2) on pg. 83 as mentioned at the bottom of pg. 88.

Comment: @Eman: Hi. I just moved so I don't have access to the book. But, if that's the case, then, once you have the estimate of $\alpha$, $\hat{\alpha}$, don't you have the estimates of the $A_{i}$.

Comment: @mlofton : Yes, but to calculate $\tilde{\alpha}$ or $\tilde{A}_i$ you need $\tilde{\mu}^*$ or $\tilde{\mu}$. However, to calculate $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\Sigma}_u$ you need $\tilde{\alpha}$ or $\tilde{A}_i$. So the equations still depend on each other as I see it.

Comment: Hi: It's a good question. I don't know. The only thing that I can think of is that $\mu$ is known ?  I remember emailing Dr. Lutkepohl in the distant past and him answering some question kindly so you may want to try emailing him. I'm sorry that that's all I have.